# Adobe Edge Animate cannot call (edgeCommons.js:3)

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

Due to my current JS ignorance, I'm unsure what this phrase means:

'uncaught typeerror: cannot call mehtod 'bootstrapCallback' of undefined ---> EdgeCommons.js:3'

This is my code which is on my stage upon COMPOSITION READY:

```
yepnope({
    load: "http://cdn.edgecommons.org/an/1.1.2/js/min/EdgeCommons.js",
    // Wait until completely loaded
    complete: function(){
        // Load first external composition into container
        EC.loadComposition("compositions/IntroRedo.html", sym.getSymbol("content"));
    }
});
```

Any obvious redflags here? Am I having a serious case of the dumbs??

Answer (score 0):

in the latest version of Edge Animate CC (v3) there is no need for using the yepnope function anymore. You can use the library panel to load external scripts (e.g. Edge Commons).

Here is my latest video to this specific topic:

http://www.edgedocks.com/content/2014/02/loading-external-scripts-edge-animate-cc-30

I put together a small sample project that uses this technique to enable the composition loader to load a tiny child composition into another:

http://temp.trendspurt.com/CompositionLoader.zip

Hope that helps!
Happy Animating,
Simon Widjaja 
(EdgeDocks.com, EdgeCommons.org)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. Why is doing it this way better than a yepnope function? Also, might this method help with loading the project on the ipad? Thanks again!